# How to create a workload model?

Tags: performance, load-testing, qa-developer

I am senior in college and I just got hired in QA. My first task is to create a workload model. However I am not sure what to do. I was hoping if anyone can point me to a good example. I have to calculate TPS, pacing, and concurrent users. Any formulas/guides are appreciated. This is my first task so I would like to make it as good as possible.

Comment: Goodread : http://www1.practicalperformanceanalyst.com/fundamentals-of-performance-capacity-management/performance-engineering-fundamentals-workload-modeling-101/#sthash.RSSQV7m6.dpbs . Also has some very good references.